# Gmail API drafts only?

Tags: gmail-api

I need the permission to on behalf of my customers create drafts in their Gmail-account, but at the same time don't open up the risk for me (or anyone) accidentally sending emails with their account using my app. Can this be done?

Both compose and modify allows me to send email too, which I want to avoid using this token.

Comment: Did you try utilizing OAuth 2.0 with `appropriate scopes`? like by only requesting  necessary permissions and ensuring proper authentication and authorization flow. So you can request the https://googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose scope for composing drafts and the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify scope for managing drafts

Comment: Do they have workspace